# How did Spivak get this equality?

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-explanation, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

I realise my last question omitted alot of info, so here is the context!
[image]

I am wondering how Spivak got the following equality:
[image]

I don't see how the two are equal; wouldn't $$Mi' <= Mi$$ if $$-mi <= Mi$$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I get it now! If when absoluted -mi is still less than Mi on the interval, then Mi' must be equal to Mi as Mi is still the sup value on the interval. If $$-mi > Mi$$ then Mi' = -mi and you refer to the previous equality.